# Generator returning Mocks that fail assert_called_with

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, mocking

I'm trying to test a script that is organized like this:

```
class Processor(object):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        pass

def my_iterator(elements):
    for element in elements:
        yield Processor(element)
```

I just want to test that a Processor object was created using each element in the iterable that was passed to `my_iterator()`.

I'm testing `Processor` separately, so I wrote a test for `my_iterator()` that looks like this:

```
import mock

from mymodule import my_iterator

class TestMyIterator(object):

    @mock.patch('mymodule.Processor')
    def test_my_iterator(self, ProcessorMock):
        vals = range(3)
        g = my_iterator(vals)

        for idx, item in enumerate(g):
            item.assert_called_with(vals[idx])
```

But when I run the test (using nosetests), it tells me that `item` was NotCalled at all. Shouldn't it have been called when `my_iterator()` yielded an element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the iterator yields an item, `ProcessorMock` is called to produce the item, but the item itself is never called. Rather than asserting that `item` was called, you should be making those assertions about `ProcessorMock`:

```
ProcessorMock.assert_called_with(vals[idx])
```